# Error on SocketConnection.StartAsync Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: asp.net-core

in my netcore app 2.1 i found some error logs that i not understand

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets   Unexpected exception in SocketConnection.StartAsync.
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'MemoryPoolBlock'.
   at System.Buffers.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Buffers.MemoryPoolBlock.Dispose()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.BufferSegment.ResetMemory()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.CompletePipe()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.CompleteWriter(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.StartAsync(IConnectionDispatcher connectionDispatcher)
```

What it refers to? How can fix that error?